# Is it safe to install Os X (iATKOS) on top of Windows 7 and Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-7, macos, ubuntu, boot

I have a laptop with this configuration :

```
Model : Acer Aspire 5742G
CPU : Intel Core i3-380m
Ram : 4GB
Disk: 500Gb
CG  : Intel HD & nVidia 610M
```

I already have windows7 and Ubuntu 14 installed, and i was wondering if i may face any sort of problem if i install osX (iATkos) on top of these two, there was a time before (4 years ago) i tried installing Windows Xp on a maching that has windows7, it worked but i wasn't able to boot on Windows7 anymore and i had to make some boot recovering or something like that, am worried that the same thing could happens now, i have very important data in this computer and it's my only working tool so even if there is a solution for an upcoming problem, i can't risk wasting 5 hours researching and fixing the problem.

Long story short, 
Can i Triple boot with Windows7 ubuntu and OsX without any problem ?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will work properly. but when you install the new OS, if you still want to boot Windows, and Ubuntu, make sure you don't install it over the two OS's, instead there will be an option where you can re partition your hard drive so that you can fit the new Operating System without harming your current two OS's =)